# Calculation raises error "Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Tags: python-3.x

So, I want to write a program with python 3 where it can help users calculate the circumference of a circle and sphere. So far this is what I have.

```
pi = 3.14159
value = input("Enter the value of your radius:")
circ = 2*pi*value
print(circ)
```

But, it keeps saying "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'". How do I fix this? And, how do I make the input as numbers only? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
value = float(input("Enter the value of your radius: "))
```

Note that this will throw an error if the input isn't a number.

Also, while you cant control what they input, you could just keep asking for a number if they type anything else like this:

`while True:
    try:
       value = float(input("Enter the value of your radius: "))
    except ValueError:
       print("Please enter a number")`

Answer (score 0):

Running your program as-is reports

```
bash-3.2$ python3 test.py
Enter the value of your radius:10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    circ = 2*pi*value
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

The problem is `value` contains a string after the `input` returns
and python is trying to multiply a float (2*pi) and the string (character sequence `value`).
To correct this you probably want to convert value to a float before the multiplication.
e.g.

```
pi = 3.14159
value = input("Enter the value of your radius:")
circ = 2*pi*float(value)
print(circ)
```

Sample run with this change

```
bash-3.2$ python3 test.py
Enter the value of your radius:10
62.8318
```